# Git pull the last push that was done

Tags: git

I have made many changes to my source files and would just like to pull the last push that was done. I would like it to delete any new files, and revert modified files to the last version. I basically want to just revert to how the origin master last was.

Is there a way to do this without deleting the directory, re-initializing git, and then cloning the repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset --hard` will bring you back to the last commit, and `git reset --hard origin/master` will bring you back to `origin/master`.

Answer (score 2):

You can revert the change

Read more:
http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just to discard all your changes

```
git checkout .
```

And then

```
git pull
```